# Detalle de pedido en el perfil de usuario

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

espero que todos estén muy bien.

Estoy en una investigación que no me ha dejado dormir. No encuentro un hook o el template de woocommerce permite agregar contenido en la página de detalle de orden en woocommerce.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen, donde está el cuadro rojo, quiero colocar el historial de pedido, es decir, mostrarle al cliente la trayectoria del pedido hasta la entrega del pedido (ver la siguiente imagen).
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no he podido encontrar el template de woocommerce o un hook que me permita agregar este contenido. Además que tampoco encuentro la manera de llamar el estado de pedido desde la base de datos, para poder hacer este desarrollo.

Espero alguien me pueda ayudar a descubrir este misterio de woocommerce, lo agradeceré infinitamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El hook para este propósito es "woocommerce_order_details_before_order_table_items". Se puede usar así:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_before_order_table', 'woo_roadmap_orders' );
function woo_roadmap_orders() {
    // Code here
}
```

Para llamar el estado del pedido la variable es:

```
wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() )
```